# Dell Precision 3571 - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dell, 22.04

I've recently received my new Dell Precision 3571, which has the following specifications:

[picture of specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHNee.png)

Currently I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed, however I have a significant amount of software only running on 20.04. On Dell's website, this computer is supposed to support 20.04. It was however bought with Windows, to get a licence for that.

When I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04, there is a significant amount of driver issues, where for example: wifi and usb-c ports does not work. This problem does not occur on 22.04, where it seems to work fine.

Does anyone have the same issue? I've installed Ubuntu many times, and I'm a bit surprised that even though Dell lists Ubuntu 20.04 as a supported OS, it does not seem to function properly.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: do you possibly need a newer kernel, or Dell's OEM version of Ubuntu? Sometimes OEM kernels (the kind that would come pre-installed if you bought the device with Ubuntu preinstalled) have updated kernels/drivers.

Comment: Hi Esther,

That might very well be. Do you by any chance know where and how I can investigate that? I did try to create the installation image through Dell's image software, which according to Dell support should help, however, it did not.

Comment: why does the software only work on 20.04? Will it work if you switch to xorg instead of wayland? Also, you can try installing a newer mainline kernel in 20.04 to see if that changes anything.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/certified/202103-28816 looks like you do need a custom image, like the one you can get from Dell. Try using an OEM kernel on 20.04, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by UEFI and an unidentified problem when dual booting ubuntu 20 and win 10. When I formatted the hard drives completely, and installed ubuntu 20 alone, it worked perfectly fine.